# how to compute $\gcd(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d})$?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

is there a formula for

$gcd(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d})?$

I'm conjeturing
$gcd(\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d})=\frac{gcd(a,c))}{lcm(b,d)}$
but how to prove it?

Comment: How do you *define* the greatest common divisor of two rational numbers?

Comment: Concerning  gcd for rationals see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831691/how-to-compute-gcd-fracab-fraccd#2831691).

Comment: What does this mean? Perhaps $\frac{\gcd(ad,bc)}{bd}$? That can be computed by Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.